# GC.KeepAlive to preserve a context

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, using, idisposable

I have a class which is is a simple wrapper for `WNetUseConnection`

Here is an implementation (just for reference):

```
internal class RemoteFileSystemContext : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _remoteUnc;
    private bool _isConnected;
    public RemoteFileSystemContext(string remoteUnc, string username, string password, bool promptUser)
    {
        if (WindowsNetworking.TryConnectToRemote(remoteUnc, username, password, promptUser))
        {
            _isConnected = true;
            _remoteUnc = remoteUnc;
        }
        else
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    ~RemoteFileSystemContext()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (!_isConnected)
            return;
        _isConnected = false;
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        WindowsNetworking.DisconnectRemote(_remoteUnc);
    }
}
```

and here is usage:

```
using (var context = WindowsNetworking.CreateRemoteContext(storagePath, login, pass))
{
    // do something with storagePath
    GC.KeepAlive(context);
}
```

The question is if I should write `GC.KeepAlive(context)` or not? I mean I didn't write code like this until I read an article (about `AsyncLock`, but now I can't find a link), and now I'm not sure if GC can call a finalizer before this method finishes. Theoretically, it should use `Dispose` in `finally` section of `using`, but this article was written by a smart guy, so I'm not sure now.

---

Just in case, I provide code for referenced class:

```
public static class WindowsNetworking
{
    public static bool TryConnectToRemote(string remoteUnc, string username, string password, bool promptUser = false)
    {
        bool isUnc = remoteUnc != null && remoteUnc.Length >= 2 && remoteUnc[0] == '\\' && remoteUnc[1] == '\\';
        if (!isUnc)
        {
            return false;
        }
        ConnectToRemote(remoteUnc, username, password, promptUser);
        return true;
    }

    public static IDisposable CreateRemoteContext(string remoteUnc, string username, string password, bool promptUser = false)
    {
        return new RemoteFileSystemContext(remoteUnc, username, password, promptUser);
    }

    public static void DisconnectRemote(string remoteUNC)
    {
        var ret = (NetworkError) WNetCancelConnection2(remoteUNC, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, false);
        if (ret != NetworkError.NO_ERROR)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception((int) ret, ret.ToString());
        }
    }

    [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
        IntPtr hwndOwner,
        NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
        string lpPassword,
        string lpUserID,
        int dwFlags,
        string lpAccessName,
        string lpBufferSize,
        string lpResult
        );

    [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(
        string lpName,
        int dwFlags,
        bool fForce
        );

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class NETRESOURCE
    {
        public int dwScope = 0;
        public int dwType = 0;
        public int dwDisplayType = 0;
        public int dwUsage = 0;
        public string lpLocalName = "";
        public string lpRemoteName = "";
        public string lpComment = "";
        public string lpProvider = "";
    }

    private static void ConnectToRemote(string remoteUNC, string username, string password, bool promptUser)
    {
        NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE
        {
            dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
            lpRemoteName = remoteUNC
        };

        NetworkError ret;
        if (promptUser)
            ret = (NetworkError) WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, "", "", CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT, null, null, null);
        else
            ret = (NetworkError) WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);

        if (ret != NetworkError.NO_ERROR)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception((int) ret, ret.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say no. Without the article, it's difficult to say what point this "smart guy" was actually making and whether you've interpreted it correctly.

Comment: It's just a history for `from where it is coming`. Question not about any guy, but about finalization.

Comment: I can say, "you don't need a `GC.KeepAlive` here". I could even post it as an answer, I'm a reasonably smart guy myself (and modest, too!), and I may even be convincing. The problem is, I don't know what point I'm arguing *against* because you cannot link to this article or say why you believe it *may* apply in this context.

Comment: It would be useful if you actually used WNetUseConnection(), what this code does is very hard to guess.  There is no obvious reason to use GC.KeepAlive() when you pinvoke anything.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for a comment, `TryConnectToRemote` actually calls `WNetUseConnection` if provided path is UNC, othervise it does nothing. I just was sure that it's not very relevant to issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GC.KeepAlive` method is [empty](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/gc.cs,279). All it does is ensure that a particular variable is read from at that point in the code, because otherwise that variable is never read from again and is thus not a valid reference to keep an object alive.

It's pointless here because the same variable that you're passing to `KeepAlive` *is* read from again at a later point in time - during the hidden `finally` block when `Dispose` is called. So, the `GC.KeepAlive` achieves nothing here.

Comment: Technically, if `Dispose` doesn't access any fields, or otherwise use the implicit reference, this isn't true (If the runtime can prove that `Dispose` doesn't need the reference to the object, it can reclaim it before executing that code), but if it references the object, then this is exactly right.

Comment: If `Dispose` doesn't actually leverage the object instance, then, from the purposes of the GC, it doesn't prolong the lifetime of the object; `GC.KeepAlive` will.  So in that one specific case, it's relevant.

Comment: This is IMHO a reason for having `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` within `Dispose` even on objects which don't have finalizers--to ensure that any nested objects which *do* have finalizers are kept alive until `Dispose` is finished.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to test, here is a quick test program, be sure it is run in release mode without a debugger attached.

```
using System;

namespace SandboxConsole
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new TestClass())
            {

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();

                Console.WriteLine("After collection");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("After dispose, before 2nd collection");

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();

            Console.WriteLine("After 2nd collection");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class TestClass : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        ~TestClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In finalizer");
            Dispose(false);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Dispose: {0}", isDisposing);
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                //uncomment this line out to have the finalizer never run
                //GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will always output

```
After collection
In Dispose: True
After dispose, before 2nd collection
In finalizer
In Dispose: False
After 2nd collection
```

---

For more concrete proof, here is the IL for the above program's Main method

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       85 (0x55)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class SandboxConsole.TestClass context)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void SandboxConsole.TestClass::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  .try
  {
    IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
    IL_000b:  call       void [mscorlib]System.GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    IL_0010:  call       void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
    IL_0015:  ldstr      "After collection"
    IL_001a:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_001f:  leave.s    IL_002b
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_0021:  ldloc.0
    IL_0022:  brfalse.s  IL_002a
    IL_0024:  ldloc.0
    IL_0025:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_002a:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_002b:  ldstr      "After dispose, before 2nd collection"
  IL_0030:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0035:  call       void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
  IL_003a:  call       void [mscorlib]System.GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
  IL_003f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
  IL_0044:  ldstr      "After 2nd collection"
  IL_0049:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_004e:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
  IL_0053:  pop
  IL_0054:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

You can see there is a hidden finally block that checks if the object is null then calls Dispose on it. That reference will keep the object alive the entire scope of the using block.

UPDATE: See [Damien's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever), this *specific* example does have the opportunity to actually call the finalizer early due to the fact I don't ever use any variables that use a implicit `this` in the dispose method. To guarantee the behavior be sure to use a instance level variable (which my short example has none) or have `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` uncommented.

Comment: A clever GC/JIT combo *may* actually be able to finalize this object earlier than the explicit `Dispose` - if it can optimize across multiple methods, nothing in your `TestClass` references any fields of the class and so the `this` references isn't required by any of the methods. Unlike the OPs class which does access local fields within the `Dispose`. So this is an observation, not a *guarantee*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Really, i did not know the JIT can go that far. Thanks for the word of warning.

Comment: I'm not aware if any do take it that far, just that it's a possibility.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The specs would allow it to, at a minimum.